# Engine turn based local multiplayer game

Tags: game-development, mobile, recommendation-engine

I am new to app development. I have experience with web development with languages such as PHP, jQuery, HTML etc. I want to take a turn at development for mobile devices.

I have a concept for a game that is a turn-based local multiplayer game. Essentially, the user would open the app, select the amount of players, choose their player avatar, edit the player name etc. and start the game. Once the game is started, each player will have their own turn in a cyclical nature (and pass the mobile device along). Obviously, the game would keep track of certain player stats as the game progresses. The graphics in the game are going to be simple and cartoons (2D).

Im curious if there is an app engine that will cater to a newbie like me as well as the game style. I have done some research on Stencyl but im not sure that this type of game will work well with that platform.

Comment: same question - i was unable to reply/login as the user that posted said question

Comment: @DimP is there any particular reason why you prefer LOVE

Comment: @DimP is there a framework that is better suited for the turn based games? or will it be better to start learning a particular framework? Also  i will need help so i will definitely need a large community to help troubleshoot

Comment: iPoo, to get back ownership of your previous post you might wish to see: [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts)

Comment: @izzy i followed the steps and everything = nada

Comment: Nothing I can do on that, it requires action from staff. Have you already received an answer? That'd be fast. If not, have a little patience. Should usually be done within a few days (I vaguely remember having had the same issue when I started at SE, and it was less than 3 days if I remember correctly).